# SQL Help Inner JOIN LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

My query is:

```
SELECT Pics.ID, Pics.ProfileID, Pics.Position, Rate.ID as RateID, Rate.Rating, Rate.ProfileID, Gender
FROM Pics
    INNER JOIN Profiles ON Pics.ProfileID = Profiles.ID
    LEFT JOIN Rate ON Pics.ID = Rate.PicID
WHERE Gender = 'female'
ORDER BY Pics.ID
```

And results are:

```
ID ProfileID Position RateID Rating ProfileID Gender
23 24        1        59     9      42        female
24 24        2        33     8      32        female
23 24        1        53     3      40        female
26 24        4        31     8      32        female
30 25        4        30     8      32        female
24 24        2        58     4      42        female
```

Now I want to do another query which would be:
If Rate.ProfileID = 32, remove any rows that contain that same Pics.ID

so left with:

```
ID ProfileID Position RateID Rating ProfileID Gender
23 24        1        59     9      42        female
23 24        1        53     3      40        female
```

and also remove any duplicate Pics.ID so just one of the above as they are both = 23 so left with :

23 24 1 59 9 42 female or 23 24 1 53 3 40 female

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Have you tried anything? When you attempted to solve your problem before posting here, what issues did you come across?

Comment: rate.profileID is on the left join.  Therefore it has to be ON the join so the exclusion retains your null values.  so... `LEFT JOIN Rate ON Pics.ID = Rate.PicID and Rate.ProfileID = 32`  if you do `LEFT JOIN Rate ON Pics.ID = Rate.PicID where gender='female' and Rate.ProfileID =32` then you basically make the left join an inner as you eliminate the nulls generated from the left join in the where clause.  Null <> 32!

Comment: Why is row `24 24 2 58 4 42 female` (last row) not in the expected results of the modified query?

Comment: @Shadow Because the 2nd row contains the Rate.ProfileID = 32, and that Pic.ID = 24, therefore it must remove ALL Pic.ID = 24, which removes the bottom row also.

Comment: @Strawberry Pic.ID

Comment: It's a little unfair to expect contributors to infer a data set from a result set. Why not provide both?

Comment: Agreed.  My given answer could probably be simplified a whole lot if I had source tables to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably get rid of "magical numbers", like 32. That said, I think that this will give you what you need.

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    P.ProfileID,
    P.Position,
    R.ID as RateID,
    R.Rating,
    R.ProfileID,
    PR.Gender
FROM
    Pics P
INNER JOIN Profiles PR ON PR.ID = P.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN Rate R ON R.PicID = P.ID
WHERE
    PR.Gender = 'female' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Pics P2
        INNER JOIN Profiles PR2 ON PR2.ID = P2.ProfileID
        INNER JOIN Rate R2 ON R2.PicID = P2.ID AND R2.ProfileID = 32
        WHERE
            P2.ID = P.ID
    )
ORDER BY
    P.ID
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried the other 2, but this is the one that does what I wanted :)

Comment: The query does not need the `Rate` table in the subquery.

Comment: It's a good answer - well laid-out.  @user2643679, did my query run for you?  It should do the exact same thing.  Unless if SQL Server complained about the lack of aliases in mine?

Answer (score 1):

> @Shadow Because the 2nd row contains the Rate.ProfileID = 32, and that
>   Pic.ID = 24, therefore it must remove ALL Pic.ID = 24, which removes
>   the bottom row also.

```
SELECT Pics.ID, Pics.ProfileID, Pics.Position, Rate.ID as RateID, Rate.Rating, Rate.ProfileID, Gender
FROM Pics
INNER JOIN Profiles ON Pics.ProfileID = Profiles.ID
LEFT JOIN Rate ON Pics.ID = Rate.PicID
WHERE Gender = 'female' AND Pics.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Pics.ID 
    FROM Pics
    INNER JOIN Profiles ON Pics.ProfileID = Profiles.ID
    LEFT JOIN Rate ON Pics.ID = Rate.PicID
    WHERE Gender = 'female' AND Rate.ProfileID = 32)

ORDER BY Pics.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Pics.ID, Pics.ProfileID, Pics.Position, Rate.ID as RateID, 
       Rate.Rating, Rate.ProfileID, Gender
FROM Pics
INNER JOIN Profiles ON Pics.ProfileID = Profiles.ID
LEFT JOIN Rate ON Pics.ID = Rate.PicID
LEFT JOIN Rate AS r 
   ON Rate.ProfileID = r.ProfileID AND Rate.ID > r.ID
WHERE Gender = 'female' AND (Pics.ProfileID <> 32) AND (r.ID IS NULL)
ORDER BY Pics.ID
```

The last `LEFT JOIN` operation helps identify duplicates using this predicate in the `ON` clause:

```
Rate.ProfileID = r.ProfileID
```

If such duplicates exist, as is the case with `Rate.ProfileID = 42`, then only the one having the *maximum* `Rate.ID` is returned due to the following conditions:

```
Rate.ID > r.ID (`ON` clause)
```

and

```
(r.ID IS NULL) (`WHERE` clause)
```